# Filling drop down with an array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, drop-down-menu

Issue seems simple but i cant find anything. I want to fill an Dropdown selection (in excel not in a userform) with the values of an array.
so far i created the array and now i only want to hand it over to an drop down. Sounds simple enough.

Here the Code for creating the Dropdown

```
Worksheet("Example").Cells(i,13).Select 'original here was a  . range but i need it to be variable therefore i used cells
    With Selection.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:= ArrayNAme 'not working
        .IgnoreBlank = False
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True

    End With
```

I dont get an error message but also no Dropdown appears. Does somebody know what iam doing wrong?

---

Some good new, some bad news ^^
A Dropdown is now created and filled. Unfortunatlly the filling isnt quite right.

The last value is always a number and the array isnt properly erased when the next loop comes so the picture is like:

First drop down: "correct value", "correct value" "2" 'there shouldnt be a number

Second drop down: "value from first dropdown", "value from first dropdown", "2", "new correct value, ...

I hope this is understanable.
Here my currecnt code.

```
Dim joinedOutput As String
Dim index As Long
For index = LBound(ArrDropdown, 1) To (UBound(ArrDropdown, 1) - 1)
    joinedOutput = joinedOutput & ArrDropdown(index) & ","
Next index
joinedOutput = joinedOutput & UBound(ArrDropdown, 1)

    Set rng = Worksheets("Transfer").Cells(j, 13)

    With rng.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:=joinedOutput
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With

   Erase ArrDropdown
```

Comment: When your array is too long, you'll receive errors when re-opening the file. You could put your array in a range and referto that range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try joining your array into a comma-delimited string. (`Vba.Strings.Join()` might help if it's a string array; if not, you might need to loop over it and use `&` concatenation operator).

Say your array is called `arr` and is 1-dimensional, you could try the below:

```
Dim joinedOutput as string
Dim index as long
For index = lbound(arr,1) to (ubound(arr,1)-1)
    If not isnumeric(arr(index)) then
        joinedOutput = joinedOutput & arr(index) & ","
    End if
Next index
If not isnumeric(arr(ubound(arr,1))) then
    joinedOutput = joinedOutput & ubound(arr,1)
End if
```

And then feed the `joinedOutput` string as the argument to the `Formula1:=` parameter below.

```
With Selection.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:=joinedOutput
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
```

Then assign (so that the new dropdown does not have the previous dropdown's values):

```
joinedOutput = vbnullstring
```

The repeat the loop. Using `&` string concatenation is inefficient in VBA, as copies of the strings involved have to be made -- but if it's okay for your use case, then it's fine to leave as is.

As Gary's Student points out in his answer, you could also just use `joinedOutput = application.textjoin(arr, ",")` (instead of the loop), although I think this function is only available if you have an Office 365 subscription.

Comment: thanks for the response, can you give me an example on how to joining into comma deliminated strings?

Comment: @G.M Sure, do you know what variable type your array is? E.g. is it declared as `Dim arr as variant` or `Dim arr() as string`, or something else?

Comment: its declared as varaint

Comment: @G.M Okay, have edited my post to include an example. Try it and see if it works, if you want.

Comment: hi there, i tried your code and it worked... a little :D see main post ^^

Comment: @G.M Sure, have edited my post. Try now if you want (it should now skip all values that are numbers, irrespective of what position they're at in the loop.)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `Selection` you should work with the range directly. Take a look at this edit of your code:

```
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim ArrayName() As Variant 'this is whatever your array is (not shown in your code)

    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Example").Cells(i, 13)

    With rng.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, _
             AlertStyle:=xlWalidAlertStop, _
             Operator:=xlEqual, _
             Formula1:=Join(ArrayName, ",")
        .IgnoreBlank = False
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
```

the `Join(ArrayName, ",")` will take the contents of your array and turn it into a String with each element separated by a ","

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using an internal VBA array converted into a string:

```
Sub InternalString()

    Dim arr(1 To 3) As String, s As String
    arr(1) = "Winken"
    arr(2) = "Blinken"
    arr(3) = "Nod"
    s = Application.WorksheetFunction.TextJoin(",", True, arr)

    With ActiveCell.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:=s
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

NOTE:

- we use the worksheet function *TextJoin()*
- *TextJoin()* can handle both VBA arrays as well as a range of worksheet cells.

Comment: Hey :) unfortunatly textjoin() didnt work for me  (error message 13). I went with the example of chillin which mostly worked ^^

Answer (score 0):

A great list of fabulous answers to the request. Here is a version where you indicate the Range where to take the items to select and the Range where to insert the new validators. Just changed the code to add a check on duplicate elements, and added code to check if array is empty.

```
Public Sub addDropDownValidator(ByRef rangeToAddDropDown As Variant, ByVal rangeListValidators As Variant)
Dim aFilledArray() As Variant, cell As range, count As Long, x As Long, strTemp As String, dupBool As Boolean

If TypeName(rangeToAddDropDown) = "Range" And TypeName(rangeListValidators) = "Range" Then
    count = 0
    dupBool = False
    For Each cell In rangeListValidators
        strTemp = Trim(cell.Value2)
        If Len(strTemp) > 0 Then
            If count > 0 Then
                dupBool = False
                For x = LBound(aFilledArray) To UBound(aFilledArray)
                    If strTemp = aFilledArray(x) Then
                        dupBool = True
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next x
            End If
            If Not dupBool Then
                If count = 0 Then
                    ReDim aFilledArray(0 To 0)
                Else
                    ReDim Preserve aFilledArray(0 To UBound(aFilledArray) + 1)
                End If
                aFilledArray(count) = strTemp
                count = count + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next cell
    If Not isArrayEmpty(aFilledArray) Then
        With rangeToAddDropDown.Validation
            .Delete
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=Join(aFilledArray, ",")
            .IgnoreBlank = True
            .InCellDropdown = True
            .InputTitle = ""
            .ErrorTitle = ""
            .InputMessage = ""
            .ErrorMessage = ""
            .ShowInput = True
            .ShowError = True
        End With
    End If
    Erase aFilledArray
Else
    MsgBox "Wrong Data Type!"
End If

End Sub

'To determine if a one-dimension array is empty; only works with one-dimension arrays
Public Function isArrayEmpty(ByVal aArray As Variant) As Boolean

On Error Resume Next
isArrayEmpty = IsArray(aArray) And Len(Join(aArray, "")) = 0
Err.Clear: On Error GoTo 0

End Function
```